# How do I make this form pop up when user click a button?

Tags: html, jquery, jsp

I have this jquery script code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("welcome");
          $("#AddFieldButton").click(function(){
                $("#AddFieldForm").css("visibility", "visible");
                $("#AddFieldForm").css("opacity", "1");
             });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/ownerMainScreen.css?version=70">
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

And this form

```
<form class="AddForm" id="AddFieldForm" method="post" action="AddField.htm">
        <label>Thêm sân</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="ID sân" name="ID"/>
        <label>Số người đá:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="SLNGUOIDA" checked="checked" class="spread" value="5">
        <label class="spread">5</label>
        <input type="radio" name="SLNGUOIDA" class="spread" value="7">
        <label class="spread">7</label>
        <input type="radio" name="SLNGUOIDA" class="spread" value="11">
        <label class="spread">11</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Giá tiền" name="GIA"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Thêm"/>
        <button id="ExitAddField" type="button">Hủy</button>
    </form>
```

And this button which I want it to make the form pop up whenever I click it

```
<div id="Fields" class="Container">
        <button class="AddButton" id="AddFieldButton">Thêm sân</button>
        <input class="SearchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search"/>
        <img class="SearchIcon" alt="Tìm kiếm" src="../resources/Icons/SearchIcon.png" width="30" height="30">
</div>
```

And the button would then activate the jquery code to alter the form's css

```
.AddForm{
    display:grid;
    background-color:rgb(200,230,200);
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 
    width: 45vw;
    height:70vh;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius:20px;
    border-color:#036932;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:2px; 
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 23.3% 10% 23.3% 10% 23.3%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, visibility 0.5s;
}
```

I tried putting a welcome alert at the start of the script and it did alert so I know it does take the script. And I slect the elements by ID so it can't be the selectors either so I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    (function($) {
        $.fn.invisible = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
            });
        };
        $.fn.visible = function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
            });
        };
    }(jQuery));
    
    
$("#AddFieldButton").click(function(){
   
    $("#AddFieldForm").invisible();
  });
```

Or, make a function and call it whenever the button is clicked.

```
function handleClick(){
     $("#AddFieldForm").invisible();
    }
```

Then call this on the button's click event.

```
<button class="AddButton" id="AddFieldButton" onClick="handleClick()">Thêm sân</button>
```

Hope this should work :)